# jQuery generate unique IDs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here's what I have:

```
<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
```

It's a PHP array, which contains some links. I need to add an extra hash parameter `#nav-link` to the end of each link.

Here's how I tried do it:

```
<a id="likeLink" href=""><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#likeLink").attr("href", <?=$arItem["LINK"]?> + "#nav-link");
    });
</script>
```

But this code doesn't work because jQuery will not know which links I am linking to. So I guess that I need to generate the unique `ids`, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Yes, all links must have `#nav-link` at the end

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For generating random ids you could use this one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Generator() {};

Generator.prototype.rand =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) + Date.now();

Generator.prototype.getId = function() {
   return this.rand++;
};
var idGen =new Generator();
</script>
</html>
<body>
<!-- Place this in the body of the page content -->

   <button onclick="console.log(idGen.getId())">click</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already saw a couple of methods how to generate the ids, but I don't know how to apply them

Comment: According the code I have e.g. 10 links with the same id, and code doesn't work correctly, because every id must be unique for every link

Comment: My humble example. Returns each time another number by simple incrementing. You can use it as you wish. It uses static methods in javascript:)

Comment: I love programmers who add extra stuff that do not understand. This function is as random as it is without `Math.random()` since you are getting the milliseconds time. Adding a random number between 0 and 25 does not turn it any more random.

Comment: In my answer I proposed a random generator, not an increment generator, so my answer is true to my code. As you know, milliseconds only grow, so they are not 'fully random'.

Comment: I'm just telling that is as random with and without random. Even a bit less random with it. Imagine that you get a 25 as a result of `Math.random() * 26` and 3 milliseconds later you get a 22 of the same expression. You could get the same number twice. If you remove the random stuff is better and faster. That's why I said you added something you didn't understand.

Answer (score 40):

I didn't need a forever unique/random id, just something that was unique per page, and all of these solutions seemed overkill for me so I came up with this:

```
const uniqId = (() => {
    let i = 0;
    return () => {
        return i++;
    }
})();

// usage:
uniqId(); // 0
uniqId(); // 1
uniqId(); // 2
// ...
```

Comment: This is the most pragmatic solution, you deserve more votes.

Comment: doesn't work, returns the "return script (function..."

Comment: Try: `var uniq = function() {var self=this; self.i = 0; self.next = function(){return self.i++;}};.  `  Use:  `var u = new Uniq(); u.next();`

Answer (score 13):

Since v1.9, jQueryUI has a builtin method for creating unique id's, called uniqueId().

This code will set a unique id on each element belonging to myclass.

```
$(".myclass").each(function () {
    $(this).uniqueId();
});
```

Note that, in my testing at least, you cannot assign a new id, if the element already has one.

So this div would get a unique id with the above Javascript code

```
<div class="myclass"/>
```

But this wouldn't

```
<div class="myclass" id="myId"/>
```

See https://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/ for more information

Comment: Note, `uniqueId()` was added in JQuery UI, and not the core library.

Comment: I think this should include a callback with the ID generated as a parameter in case you want to store it in an array or something

Answer (score 9):

I always use following code to generate unique ids. I've found this method several years ago on Stackoverflow:

```
 /**
 * Create a random Guid.
 *
 * @return {String} a random guid value.
 */
newGuid: function() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,
    function(c) {
      var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
        v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    }).toUpperCase();
}
```

And you are able to find other useful js helpers in my library: 
https://github.com/mazong1123/neatjs

Comment: i tried this and it failed creating unique ids if you post multiple 5 things all at once. Can you provide a better one?

Answer (score 4):

We can create a unique id for the elements using 
[uniqueId()](http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId) in Underscore:

> ## uniqueId
>
> ```
>  _.uniqueId([prefix])
> ```
>
> Generate a globally-unique id for client-side models or DOM elements that need one. If **prefix** is passed, the id will be appended to it.
>
> ```
> _.uniqueId('contact_');
> => 'contact_104'
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you call the code in some kind of loop, you could just replace

```
<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
```

with

```
<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>#nav-link"><?=$arItem["TEXT"]?></a>
```

that way "#nav-link" is added at the end of each link. No javascript or jquery needed at all :D

Comment: PHP is executing on the server side and after first click I get a link, and only after second click I get my link with hashtag

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quit understand. Can you try to explain a little more. After second click on what? When is PHP executed on the server? Do you have some kind of Ajax?

Comment: I have 10 links in the PHP array. These links are displayed on the site just like a list. But when I click the link, I get only a link without any hashtag bacause PHP executes on the server side. When I click the link second time, I already get what I need

Comment: What do you mean by "When I click the link second time, I already get what I need". Do you not want the hashes when you load the page again or are you on a different page?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year old now, however, the OP stated he did not know 'how' to apply the IDs. This can be accomplished easily using the rand prototype by [beri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086177/beri) above as used here.

```
/// insure ALL myClass elements have a unique ID. 
if(!$('.myClass').attr("id")){
    $('.myClass').attr("id",idGen.getId());
    console.log($('.myClass').attr("id"));
}
```

or using a much broader brush:

```
/// insure ALL anchor tags have a unique ID. 
if(!$('a').attr("id")){
    $('a').attr("id",idGen.getId());
}
```