# How to handle dynamically created tr in table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with ajax where user can request multiple ajax at a single time. For each user request i am creating a tr in table which show a current process of user request.

User can request a multiple file at a time. In this table two files are uploading multiple time with linux command.

And my ajax code is :-

```
$('#mxf').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            d = new Date();
            $.ajax({
                url     : $(this).attr('action'),
                type    : $(this).attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data    : $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() {
                    var row = '<tr>';
                        row += '<td>'+$('#fileid').val()+'</td>';   
                        row += '<td>'+$('#ndrive').val()+'</td>';   
                        row += '<td>date</td>';
                        row += '<td>time</td>';
                        row += '<td><div id="process-bar" class="process-bar">&nbsp;</div></td>';
                        row += '</tr>'; 
                    $('#stastistics tbody').prepend(row);   
                    $('#fileid').val('');
                    $('#ndrive').val('');                 
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    if(data.status == 'error')
                    {
                        var html = '<span class="label label-danger">Error</span>';
                        $("tr td:nth-child(5)").find('#process-bar').remove();
                        $("tr td:nth-child(5)").html(html);
                    }
                    else if(data.status == 'success')
                    {
                        var html = '<span class="label label-success">Success</span>';
                        $("tr td:nth-child(5)").find('#process-bar').remove();
                        $("tr td:nth-child(5)").html(html);
                    }
                    },
                error   : function( xhr, err ) {
                 },
            });    
        });
```

- In beforeSend function i am creating a new row for every request
- in success method i am updating a 5th td "processing" to "Success" or "Error".

Now i have a problem that every success or failure method  $("tr td:nth-child(5)").html(html); this line updating all 5th td of all rows.

So how can i handle only current processes rows 5th td. So it will update only single row's 5th td

thanks

Comment: You need to make your selector more specific.  You could generate a unique id or marker class for your tr or td per request.

Comment: but how can i find which request is giving response so i handle the particular tr. @BJSafdie

Comment: I am on my iPad and writing code is horribly cumbersome.  I will add an answer when I get in front of a real keyboard, if no one else has chimed in by then.

Comment: your help will be really appreciable @BJSafdie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a unique id or marker class and add that to your html.  You can generate the id into a variable that will be available to your Ajax success method via closure.  You can generate a unique id using a library like underscore.js or roll your own, as shown in this Stack Overflow post:  [jQuery generate unique IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203453/jquery-generate-unique-ids).  My example will use underscore.  Note that you could also just set the id on the table cell, if you do not need easy access to the rest of the row.  I also execute the selector once and save the result in $cell for reuse. This is a bit more efficient.

```
$('#mxf').on('submit', function(event){
            var d = new Date(), // you had this as a global
                tempId = _.uniqueId("row_");
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url     : $(this).attr('action'),
                type    : $(this).attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data    : $(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function() {
                    var row = '<tr ' + 'id="' + tempId + '">';
                        row += '<td>'+$('#fileid').val()+'</td>';   
                        row += '<td>'+$('#ndrive').val()+'</td>';   
                        row += '<td>date</td>';
                        row += '<td>time</td>';
                        row += '<td><div id="process-bar" class="process-bar">&nbsp;</div></td>';
                        row += '</tr>'; 
                    $('#stastistics tbody').prepend(row);   
                    $('#fileid').val('');
                    $('#ndrive').val('');                 
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    var $cell = $("tr#" + tempId + " td:nth-child(5)");
                    if(data.status == 'error')
                    {
                        var html = '<span class="label label-danger">Error</span>'; 
                        $cell.find('#process-bar').remove();
                        $cell.html(html);
                    }
                    else if(data.status == 'success')
                    {
                        var html = '<span class="label label-success">Success</span>';
                        $cell.find('#process-bar').remove();
                        $cell.html(html);
                    }
                    },
                error   : function( xhr, err ) {
                 },
            });    
        });
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: If it works, don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Comment: Thank you for the up vote, but to accept the answer, you need to click the check mark outline below the vote count.  This post shows screenshots: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work