# How can I generate unique key for each user?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cross-domain, setcookie

I make a jquery popup box that shows some information to user with accept button. When user enter my site, user will see that popup box.

At this time, I save `wait` in the `'answer'` column of the database table  with user id.

If user click accept button, I update from `wait` to `yes` in the `'answer'` column for that user id and not show popup box for that user in today.

If user not click accept button and reload the page, show popup box again because the `wait` state is not change for that user id and user can't do anything.

I already finish that part and every thing is fine.

Now I want to use that popup from another website.

Assume that, I already create popup box in `a.com` and I want to also use that popup procedure from `b.com` or any other website.

So, I created a script that can access popup of `a.com` from any other website like this,

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.ui/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
<link href="/css/jquery-ui-1.11.4.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class","popup");
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var id =  '1234';//I need to assign different value for each user
    var stype = "static";
    $(".popup").load("http://a.com/popup/popup_proce.php,{unique_id:id,script_type:stype}");
});
</script>
```

This script can show popup procedure. But, the problem is, if the user click accept button, I need to check that user is already click accept button or not.

So, I need to know the unique id for each user to save that record into database.

And I don't want to show popup for the user in today if the user already seen popup and click accept button in today.

The main problem is I need to generate cookie as id for each user in the above script because I need to check this user is already accept popup or not and need to save that user data.

If I use random value for id, I can't check that user is already accept or not(still `wait` state). Because when I reload(refresh) the page, random id is changed and it save as new id.

So, I can't check the `wait` state of previous id and it always save as new id when I refresh the page. That is the problem for me.

So, I think, instead of random value, I need to create cookie for each user id.

When I try with cookie like this,

```
document.cookie = "unique_id=123456";
var id = document.cookie;
```

I can't access that cookie result from `a.com`. I think I was wrong. I don't have a lot of experience in cookie with cross domain.

I'm very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: Here's how you do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203453/jquery-generate-unique-ids

Comment: Sorry, I'm forgot to explain some condition. Now, I already update my question. Please check me again.

Answer (score 1):

At least you can try following code to generate a custom UUID:

```
function getNewID()
{
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    if (window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === "function")
    {
        d += performance.now();
        ; // use high-precision timer if available
    }
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c)
    {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm forgot to explain some condition of my procedure. Now, I update my question with a little more precise explanation. Can you Please check me again. Thank you

Comment: well as I experienced, reading cookies via cross-domain is not possible due to security reasons. So if I understood that allright your database is on site A and your popups on site B. From site A you cannot read cookies of site B. So you need to read the cookie in the popup-skript on site B and send that value to site A where you match it with your database and then decide whether to show the popup or not. That's my best idea to solve this

Comment: Thank you. I'll will try as you said