# JavaScript function is failing to clone table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

To give you some context of my situation, In my my code an item can have parts, with these parts the user can harvest, transfer, or dispose of them. For example, a item can have 5 parts. Right now when the user selects a radio box option it will handle all of these parts the same way. So I have created a checkBox option where a user can 'de-select' the "All" option. I then want this to create two identical rows so that the user can have options, for example , transfer 2, harvest 2, dispose of 1.

I have a checkbox that calls my jQuery function that looks like this

I have a checkbox field inside my row that calls my jQuery function when it is clicked, it looks like this

```
<tr class="tr_clone">
<td>
    @part.PartIDLink
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
 </td>
<td style="font-weight:bold">
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" onchange="doalert(this.id, @part.ID)" checked>
</td>
@foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
{
   <td>
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType)
   </td>
}
</tr>
```

And here is my JQuery function

```
<script>
 function doalert(id, rowID) {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $clone.find('td');
        $tr.after($clone);
 }
</script>
```

Here is the rendered HTML

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        IGT Part ID
      </th>
      <th>
        Part Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Qty used in Item
      </th>
      <th>
        Move All
      </th>
      <th style="color:blue">
        Transfer
      </th>
      <th style="color:forestgreen">
        Harvest
      </th>
      <th style="color:red">
        Dispose
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr class="tr_clone" ">
    <td>
      <a p-id="346 " style="color:#FF00FF; " href="# ">600601</a>
    </td>                               
    <td>
      Supply - Packing Carton, 9" x 8 " x 8", MU/AX <input id="Parts_0__PartName" name="Parts[0].PartName" type="hidden" value="Supply - Packing Carton, 9&quot; x 8&quot; x 8&quot;, MU/AX">
    </td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">
      1
      <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field QtyInItem must be a number." data-val-required="The QtyInItem field is required." id="Parts_0__QtyInItem" name="Parts[0].QtyInItem" type="hidden" value="1">

    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="all346" onchange="doalert(this.id,346)" checked="">
    </td>

    <td>
      <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedActionType field is required." id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Transfer">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Harvest">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Parts_0__SelectedActionType" name="Parts[0].SelectedActionType" type="radio" value="Dispose">
    </td>
  </tr>
```

But it is not cloning the table row. Why is this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: The `find()` line in your code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Note that IDs must be unique to the document. After cloning, you have two elements with the same ID, which would cause problems.

Comment: The value of `this` is `window` when the function is called. (This is why inline event handlers are usually a bad idea – when using jQuery, use it to attach the event handlers as well.)

Comment: @HereticMonkey how would I clone the row, giving it a different ID? And okay I removed the Val(' ') now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203453/jquery-generate-unique-ids

Comment: @isherwood but is them having the same id's the reason for the issue? Or is that just ann after the fact something to watch out for thing

Comment: No, ID values aren't a factor. That's just good advice. You have a markup issue that could be a factor: `<tr class="tr_clone"">`

Comment: [\*cough\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002856/javascript-function-is-failing-to-clone-table-row#comment111413393_63002856)

Comment: @GuyIncognito The 'this' isn't important to what I'm doing right now so I removed it, still doesn't work

Comment: ??? `var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');` isn't important?

Comment: @GuyIncognito ohhh I thought you were talking about me passing in the ```this.id``` into the method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `this` is the issue, but Guy Incognito's hint doesn't tell the whole story. With jQuery, `$(this)` usually refers to the event target on a proper event handler. Since you aren't using one, it's null.

Instead of your inline change handler, bind the event in your script like this:

```
$('.tr_clone input.some-class').change(function() { // where some-class is on the checkbox
    let Id = $(this).attr('id');
    // set this attribute in your template
    let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');

    // ...
}
```

To pass the value of `partId` from your template, use a data attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" data-partId="@(part.ID)" class="some-class">
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a little bit confused about this part ```// set this attribute in your template
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');```

Comment: Answer updated. You may need to adjust the syntax for your template. I'm guessing.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this but I still can't duplicate the row. This is what mine looks like ```$('.tr_clone input.some-class').change(function () { let Id = $(this).attr('id'); let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId'); var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone'); var $clone = $tr.clone(); $clone.find('td');$tr.after($clone);}```  And my checkbox looks like this                                                                         ``` <input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" class="some-class" data-partId="@(part.ID)" checked> ```

Comment: If you're expecting the clones to have the same event handlers you'd need to use the `clone()` function's `true` argument or event delegation: https://jsfiddle.net/3s9ehdwk/1/

Comment: Hmm it's strange I just can't get it to clone the row. Even after comparing with yours

Comment: Please set up a fiddle demonstrating your problem if you'd like more help.

Comment: When I put it into fiddle it works, this is really frustrating

Comment: It isn't even hitting the Jquery

Comment: You would need to put that inside `document.ready` if it isn't already.